# $x,y,z$ are integers and $p$ is prime. if $x^{p-1}+y^{p-1}=z^{p-1}$ then $p\mid xyz$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am struggling with this problem. 
Suppose $x,y,z$ are integers and $p$ is prime. If $ x^{p-1}+y^{p-1}=z^{p-1}$ then $p|xyz$. I know that since the equation has a solution, so basically $p-1$ must be $2$ which means $p$ is $1$ or $p-1=2$ so $p=3$. Basically I need to prove that $2|xyz$ and $3|xyz$. I do not know how to move from there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please use mathjax to format

Comment: @KSplitX I do not have it i am sorry , I will try to edit it using word

Comment: @JamieJohn This site itself "*has*" MathJax, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick introduction.

Comment: @KSplitX Thank you that will definitely help alot

Comment: You just have to learn it its already inbuilt . Basically it usually works if you surrond your math using dollar signs

Comment: If you find any answer useful, please accept the best answer [See : How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

So, suppose $p \nmid xyz$. Then, from Fermat's theorem,
$$
x^{p-1}\equiv y^{p-1} \equiv z^{p-1} \equiv1 (mod \ p)$$
which gives us a contradiction, as $x^{p-1}+y^{p-1}\equiv 2 (mod \ p)$, while $z^{p-1}\equiv 1 (mod \ p)$.

Comment: Thank you!, I also thought about proving that xyz is multiple of 2 and 3 respectively would that work?

Comment: @JamieJohn Using Fermat Last Theorem to reduce to the case $p=2$ or $p=3$ is a huge overkill. If this is an assignment problem I would return it asking you to prove the Fermat Last Theorem....

Comment: No, I am using Fermat's Little Theorem, not the last theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $2 \nmid xyz  \implies x=2i+1~, y=2j+1~, z=2k+1$,Putting this into your equation : $$x^{p-1}+y^{p-1}=z^{p-1}$$

We get LHS even and RHS odd, thus a contradiction. Therefore $2 \mid xyz$

Using similar arguement you can prove that $3 \mid xyz$ (You'll have to take $x,y $ and $z$ as $3i+2$ and $3i+1$)

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, I just want to know if 2 doesnt divide xyz then how can you conclude it doesnt divide them individually?

Comment: @JamieJohn Because if it doesn't divide there product, none of them is even.Therefore, each of $x,y$ and $z$ is odd.